# Calculate output size in CNN

Tags: output, conv-neural-network, size

What will be the output size of each layer in the following model?

'''

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (8, 8), padding='same', strides=(4, 4), input_shape=(80,80,4)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (4, 4), padding='same', strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
```

'''

[Full Traceback (most recent call)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKZhf.png)

Comment: Have you tried `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'model.png', show_shapes =True)`?

Comment: No, I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: It's throwing an assertion error!

Comment: What's the assertion condition that's failing?

Comment: You need to post the full traceback.

Comment: @PiyushAggarwal Any chance you found my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** *If "output size" means number of parameters, here's that plus memory size of model and memory required to train:*

```
-------------------------------------
Layer                   # of Params  
=====================================
Conv2D                  544
-------------------------------------
Conv2D                  8256
-------------------------------------
Conv2D                  36928
-------------------------------------
Dense                   13107712
-------------------------------------
Dense                   1026
=====================================
Total # of Params: 13154466
Model Size: 59.47 MiB
Memory Required to Train: 1.95 GiB
-------------------------------------
```

*and here are the relevant equations to compute each:*

**Model:**

2D Conv Layer:

```
nw = kw * kh * d * d_prev  
nb = d 
n = nw + nb
```

Dense Layer:

```
nw = no * ni  
nb = no  
n = nw + nb
```

**Training:**

2D Conv Layer:

```
n = wi * hi * dl
```

Dense Layer:

```
n = no
```

**Legend:**

nw = Number of Weight Parameters
nb = Number of Bias Parameters
kw = Kernel Width
kh = Kernel Height
d = Depth of Current Layer
d_prev = Depth of Previous Layer
no = Number of outputs
ni = Number of inputs
nt = Number of training parameters
n = Total number of parameters

*For a batch size of 1, **59.47 MiB** to train. For a batch size of 32, **1.95 GiB** to train.*

---

A great resource is *Memory Usage Computational Considerations, by Kevin McGuinness*. You can watch his presentation on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hqtg7fznlnM). He gives a link to slides in the info portion of the YouTube post, but they are [here](http://imatge-upc.github.io/telecombcn-2016-dlcv/) for your reference (look for D2L1 (Day 2, Lecture 1).

It depends on four things:

1. The size of your data types,
2. The number of parameters in your model,
3. The number of parameters required to store training outputs, and
4. Your batch size

By default, `tensorflow` uses 32-bit floating point data types (these are 4 bytes in size since there are 8 bits to a byte).

Here's the code I wrote to calculate it. It's pretty much the same as what `keras` will output, but also includes memory requirements

**Source Code:**

```py
def model_params_Conv2D(d_n, k_w, k_h, d_n_prev, s_x=1, s_y=1):
    """Calculate the number of model parameters in a 2D Convolution Layer

    Args:
        d_n ([int]): Depth of current layer
        k_w ([int]]): Kernel width
        k_h ([int]): Kernel height
        d_n_prev ([int]): Depth of previous layer
        s_x ([int]): Strides in x-direction
        s_y ([int]): Strides in y-direction

    Returns:
        [int]: Number of layer parameters
    """
    n_w = d_n * k_w * k_h * d_n_prev // (s_x * s_y)  # Number of weight paramters
    n_b = d_n  # Number of bias parameters

    return n_w + n_b


def model_params_Dense(n_o, n_i):
    """Calculate the number of model parameters in a dense layer

    Args:
        n_o ([int]): Number of output
        n_i ([int]): Number of inputs

    Returns:
        [int]: Number of layer parameters
    """
    n_w = n_o * n_i  # Number of weight parameters
    n_b = n_o  # Number of bias parameters

    return n_w + n_b


def training_params_Conv2D(w_i, h_i, d_l):
    """Calclate number of training parameters in a 2D Convolution layer

    Args:
        w_i (int): Input width
        h_i (int): Input height
        d_l (int): Layer depth
    """
    return w_i * h_i * d_l


def training_params_Dense(n_o):
    """Calculate the number of training parameters in a Dense layer

    Args:
        n_o (int): Number of outputs
    """
    return n_o


def memory_requirement(n_p, m_dt=4):
    """Size of neural network model in bytes

    Args:
        n_p ([int]): Number of parameters
        m_dt ([int]): Memory size of data type in bytes
    Returns:
        [int]: Memory consumption in bytes
    """
    return n_p * m_dt


def SI2ibi(mem):
    """Convert from SI bytes to ibibytes

    Computers use powers of 2, so memory is represented in ibibytes, but
    SI prefixes are powers of 1000)

    kibi (KiB) = (2^10)^1, kilo (KB) = (10^3)^1 (1.024 KiB = 1 KB)
    mebi (MiB) = (2^10)^2, mega (MB) = (10^3)^2 (1.048576 MiB = 1 MB)
    gibi (GiB) = (2^10)^3, giga (GB) = (10^3)^3 (1.073741824 GiB = 1 GB)

    Args:
        mem ([int]): Memory size in bytes
    """
    KB = 10 ** 3
    MB = KB ** 2
    GB = KB ** 3

    KB2KiB = 1 / 1.024
    MB2MiB = 1 / 1.048576
    GB2GiB = 1 / 1.073741824

    if mem >= GB:
        mem /= GB * GB2GiB
        units = "GiB"
    elif mem >= MB:
        mem /= MB * MB2MiB
        units = "MiB"
    else:  # mem >= KB
        mem /= KB * KB2KiB
        units = "KiB"

    return mem, units


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # NOTE: Activation layers don't require any parameters. Use depth of
    #  input as d_n_prev of first layer.

    input_shape = (80, 80, 4)
    w_i = input_shape[0]  # Input width
    h_i = input_shape[1]  # Input height
    d_i = input_shape[2]  # Input depth

    conv01_params = model_params_Conv2D(
        d_n=32, k_w=8, k_h=8, d_n_prev=d_i, s_x=4, s_y=4
    )
    conv02_params = model_params_Conv2D(d_n=64, k_w=4, k_h=4, d_n_prev=32, s_x=2, s_y=2)
    conv03_params = model_params_Conv2D(d_n=64, k_w=3, k_h=3, d_n_prev=64)
    dense01_params = model_params_Dense(n_i=w_i * h_i * d_i, n_o=512)
    dense02_params = model_params_Dense(n_i=512, n_o=2)

    num_model_params = (
        conv01_params + conv02_params + conv03_params + dense01_params + dense02_params
    )

    header_ = "Layer\t\t\t# of Params"
    len_header_ = len(repr(header_.expandtabs()))
    bar_eq_ = "=" * len_header_
    bar_dash_ = "-" * len_header_

    num_training_params = training_params_Conv2D(w_i, h_i, 32)
    num_training_params += training_params_Conv2D(w_i, h_i, 64)
    num_training_params += training_params_Conv2D(w_i, h_i, 64)
    num_training_params += training_params_Dense(512)
    num_training_params += training_params_Dense(2)

    model_memory = memory_requirement(num_model_params)
    training_memory = memory_requirement(num_training_params)
    total_memory = model_memory + training_memory

    batch_size = 32

    mem, units = SI2ibi(total_memory)
    mem32, units32 = SI2ibi(total_memory * batch_size)

    print(f"{bar_dash_}")
    print(f"{header_}")
    print(f"{bar_eq_}")
    print(f"Conv2D\t\t\t{conv01_params}")
    print(f"{bar_dash_}")
    print(f"Conv2D\t\t\t{conv02_params}")
    print(f"{bar_dash_}")
    print(f"Conv2D\t\t\t{conv03_params}")
    print(f"{bar_dash_}")
    print(f"Dense\t\t\t{dense01_params}")
    print(f"{bar_dash_}")
    print(f"Dense\t\t\t{dense02_params}")
    print(f"{bar_eq_}")
    print(f"Total # of Params: {num_model_params}")
    print(f"Model Size: {mem:.2f} {units}")
    print(f"Memory Required to Train: {mem32:.2f} {units32}")
    print(f"{bar_dash_}")
```